# How to access ng-init variables using div DOM element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

in the below code, variables are defined using `ng-init` directive, angular expression gives the access to those variables,

```
    <body ng-app="">
        <div ng-init="arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];obj={x:1}">
            {{arr[0]}}
        </div>
    </body>
```

---

Using javascript code,

```
    <body ng-app="">
        <div ng-init="arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];obj={x:1}">
            <script  type="text/javascript">
             //access arr[0] using div DOM object
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
```

---

I learnt that the data is directly binded to view(DOM).

To know the under-hood working of `ng-init` directive, How do I access `arr[0]` using `div` DOM element?

Comment: thats a very bad pattern - what is your end game?

Comment: You need to create a module and controler with a $scope.

Comment: As has been mentioned by multiple people, this is an anit-pattern.  The documentation for `ng-init` clearly states that you should use a controller to initialize your variables whenever possible.  Instead, you are trying to *not* initialize them in the controller, but use them there anyway (which makes no sense).  On top of that, `ng-app=""` isn't even a valid way to bootstrap angular in any of the current supported releases.

Comment: perhaps if you described what problem you are trying to solve inside that `<script>` tag, instead of just asking how you can get access to something that doesn't belong there in the first place, this might be less of an XY Question.

Comment: that question doesn't explain what you are trying to do here.  Not only was that question and answer written two years ago, it was also written against a completely deprecated version of angular.  On top of that, it **still** doesn't explain what the `<script>` is actually *doing*, and why angular couldn't do whatever it is you are trying to make happen.

Comment: To me, this feels like you are not really clear about how the angular framework functions and how to apply it's methods to the problem you are trying to solve.  If you can explain your problem, instead of your attempted solution of using `ng-init`, perhaps we can show you the [angular way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542) to solve the problem.

Comment: @Claies which problem are you talking about? Please read my edited question

Comment: I have read every edit.  You are asking how to use something for a purpose it wasn't designed for, and haven't provided a single line of the code inside the script block to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it **only** in controller. The code inside controller will look like this:

```
var value = $scope.arr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add angular components to your app. First add the module of your app and than add the controller of this scope.

```html
<html>
    <body ng-app="App">
            <div ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-init="init()">
                {{arr[0]}}
            </div>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script  type="text/javascript">
                var app = angular.module('App',[]);
                app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                  $scope.arr = [];
                  $scope.obj = {};
                  $scope.init = function(){
                    $scope.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
                    $scope.obj={x:1};
                  };

                }]);  
                  
            </script>
           

    </body>
</html>
```